# Collapse navbar on all size except large

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a simple bootstrap navbar on my project. Such as demonstrated on the bootstrap example page:https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

**I'd like to be able to collapse it and show only the little caret-icon to expand the menu "mobile like" in all screen size except large**.

I want to display the full menu only on screen larger than 1200px.

On our project we can't modify the base bootstrap scss files as it's used widely in child projects.

**I tried to play with `visible-lg-block` on the navbar-toggle button** and `hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md` on the menu items but it doesn't work as expected. The carret icon is displayed just to the right of the brand text and not pulled on the right of the navbar. I tried with pull-right with no effect.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use media query with overriding the navbar css class as follows to keep them in collapsed mode till max size 1200px. Add the following css rules within a css file and make sure to add this custom css file right after the bootstrap css file link in the head tag.

```
/*To keep the navbar collapsed on less or equal to 1200px screens size*/
   @media (max-width: 1200px) {
     .navbar-header {
          float: none;
      }

     .navbar-toggle {
          display: block;
      }

     .navbar-collapse {
          border-top: 1px solid transparent;
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
      }

     .navbar-collapse.collapse {
          display: none!important;
      }

     .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
          display: block !important; 
      }

     .navbar-nav {
          float: none!important;
          margin: 7.5px -15px;
      }

     .navbar-nav > li {
          float: none;
      }

     .navbar-nav > li > a {
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
  }
```

Sample code: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/jVaQyX